# NHibernate mysql identity

Tags: mysql, nhibernate

I use Int32 for identity column in MySql database. I use `Session.Get<User>(1)`, it works all right. But if I use native sql by CreateSqlQuery it complains the type System.UInt32 can not be assigned to a property of type `System.Int32` setter of `User.Id`.

I checked the id column of the table as `id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment`.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should try making the User.Id type `System.UInt32` to match what is coming from the database.